# Interaction Triggers Embedded in ContentControl

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, styles, contentcontrol

So to keep the question simple what I need for example is to use something like this dozens of times;

```
    <Rectangle>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
             <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                  <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="AnotherObjectOnTheView"
                                           PropertyName="Visibility"
                                           Value="Visible" />                           
             </i:EventTrigger>                        
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   </Rectangle>
```

Except obviously I don't want to paste that dozens of times everywhere I need it. So I tried to plop them in a `ContentControl`, something like this;

```
<Style x:Key="MyThingy" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Rectangle>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="AnotherObjectOnTheView"
                                                     PropertyName="Visibility"
                                                     Value="Visible" />                                         
                        </i:EventTrigger>                        
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Rectangle>                    
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

With the idea I could substitute all of that per instance by just calling the template like;

```
<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource MyThingy}"/>
```

Except the problem is, when embedded in `ContentControl`, the Interaction Triggers don't appear to fire off. It will display the templated item fine, but seems to ignore the triggers?

So the question is, Why are the triggers attached to the templated item getting ignored, or, is there a better way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that the `Interaction.Triggers` aren't being called - they ARE being called, it's the `ChangePropertyAction` which is problematic.

For example, this will work fine:

```
    <Style x:Key="MyThingy" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl"> 
                    <Rectangle Fill="Red">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                 PropertyName="Visibility"
                                                 Value="Collapsed" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Rectangle>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Notice the only changes I did were 1. Make the rectangle red (so you can better see when it disappears) and 2. Make the trigger hide the rectangle as soon as you click the button.

So why is my code working? Because instead of using `TargetName`, I'm using `TargetObject` and binding to the templated parent. You cannot target elements in the template via name, it's a different namescope, also as far as I recall TargetName doesn't work in Styles at all, only in ControlTemplate.Triggers

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to make the `Rectangle` disappear on Mouse Click, I'm trying to make another object on the same view become `Visible` outside of the `ControlTemplate` instead (hence the `TargetName="AnotherObjectOnTheView"`) so say I have an object on the same view as the style template named 'AnotherObjectOnTheView" and I want dozens of places you can click to make it `Visible` which is where the Rectangles and Triggers come in. I tried the TargetObject but it doesnt seem to make "AnotherObjectOnTheView" visible :/

Comment: @ChrisW. Your question was _"Why are the triggers attached to the templated item getting ignored"_ which the answer is - They aren't, you're not using the `ChangePropertyAction` correctly as I showed in my answer. Your new question is something like _"Can I change a property of another control from a Style binding using the TargetName attribute"_ and the answer is *no*, this cannot be done. I'd recommend something like a 'EventToCommand' to trigger a change in the ViewModel. For example a bool property in the ViewModel which the `AnotherObjectOnTheView` 's `Visibility` will bind to.

Comment: Or directly use the `ChangePropertyAction` to change that property in the ViewModel (by binding to the DataContext of the MainWindow/UserControl)

Comment: Ah ya, so now my questions answered in a couple ways. First I forgot the `IsHitTestVisible=True` (which is what Fill also accomplishes.) As well as the inability to interact with controls outside of the template via changeproperty without wiring into the VM. Thanks Blachshma! :)